# Can I make a daily reward function in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, function

In my MySQL database, there is a column named "heart" like:

```
ID  NAME  HEART
001 AAA   5
002 BBB   22
003 CCC   15
004 DDD   12
```

So how can I make daily reward function that if user login everyday, they will get one more heart everyday. Is there any example about this? Many thanks.

Comment: use update query if user logs in ,to update the value of hearts

Comment: So how can I make a daily login check?

Comment: Not daily ,at every login you should update it

Comment: For every login you give hearts or for day based login?

Comment: I give heart for day based

Comment: then you can use cron jobs

Answer (score 0):

Use cron in linux. Write script and run every day
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Comment: If user logs in today,heart will get update tomorrow?

Comment: yes becasue if you run update every time user lg in than user can earn 10 hearts a day, buy if you run one query for example at 00:01 you add only one heart

Comment: Can you give me an example script that I can run in php?

Comment: You use cron in linux system not in php. Check this http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/ you can learn how run php scripts in cron